# MediaPlayer onCompletionListener called while paused

Tags: android, media-player

My media player for some reason completes while it is paused. Now i have seen another post that said about it being async and 300ms difference and that I understand. But my main problem is that i have 20 seconds left on the video and while paused it finishes after the 20 seconds run out.
here is the relevant code that I might have messed up on:

```
    private void initPlayer()
{
    try {
        if(videoFile != null)
        {

            afd = getAssets().openFd(videoFile);

            instructionVideoPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            instructionVideoPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());

            instructionVideoPlayer.setDisplay(holder);

            instructionVideoPlayer.prepare();
            Log.i("Instruction Video", "videoPrepared");
            instructionVideoPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(instructionVideoComplete);
            instructionVideoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        }

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(this.toString(), "IOEXception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        //initPlayer();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("InitPlayer", e.getClass().toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    restoreOverlayState();
}
```

The listeners:

```
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener instructionVideoComplete = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        Log.i("onCompletion", "called");
        if(!videoFile.contentEquals(LangSelect.INSTRUCTION_05))
        {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra(LangSelect.ACTION, LangSelect.GO_VIDEO_NEXT);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            continuePlaying = true;
            toFinish();

        }
        else
            toFinish();
    }
};

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) 
{
    playVideo();
}
```

the play and pause functions

```
    private void playVideo()
{
    instructionVideoPlayer.seekTo(pausedAt);
    instructionVideoPlayer.start();
    restoreOverlayState();
}
private void pauseVideo()
{
    pausedAt = instructionVideoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    instructionVideoPlayer.pause();
}

private void restoreOverlayState()
{
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(SAVE_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(prefs.getBoolean(IS_PAUSED, false))
    {
        pauseOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pauseVideo();
    }
    else
    {
        pauseOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Edit: this only happens on the Nexus S (2.3.3) one of the phones I am testing on. The other Galaxy S(Froyo) does not have this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing Wrong. the OnCompletionListener was being called. The problem was I was running 2 media players and setting the same onCompletionlistener to them accidentally as I was calling initPlayer twice. Once in surfaceCreated and again at the end of onResume(). Either the Galaxy S is messed up or it has weird error checking becasue this problem didnt show up there.